# Automate Killing of Matching Processes with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a script (.sh) that I can use to kill processes in one command.

When I do `$ pgrep -f vmware`

It shows a list of:

```
2234
2241
2251
2296
4751
```

Now I need to do for each one `sudo kill -9 4751`

Is there a way to automate this into

`sh sudokiller.sh vmware` then it will do the task automatically? Or there's a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
for pid in `pgrep -f vmware` ; do
    sudo kill -9 $pid
done
```

Or, just use

```
sudo killall -9 vmware
```

Comment: Can also converted into function, with `for pid in $(pgrep -f $1)...`

Answer (score 3):

You want `pkill`; it has pretty much the exact same command line options as `pgrep`:

```
$ pkill -?
Usage: pkill [-SIGNAL] [-fvx] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST]
    [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]
```

In fact, on my system (Slackware 14.1) `/usr/bin/pgrep` is actually a symlink to `/usr/bin/pkill`, that searches when run as `pgrep`, and kills when run as `pkill`.

Example:

```
me@host:~$ pgrep -f test.sh
1927
1932
1937
1945
1950
1955
1960
1965
1970
1975
1980
me@host:~$ pkill -f test.sh
me@host:~$ pgrep -f test.sh
me@host:~$
```